# NSTableView row Selection

Tags: macos, nstableview

How to move to another NSViewController on click of a row in NSTableView.
In iphone easily we can implement didselectrow and push to the needed viewcontroller.I am new to mac os development.Please help!

I am working on the storyboard, currently the scenario is FirstViewController with NSTableView, on click of the row , need to move to next view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should implement SelectionDidChange delegate method of NSTableview just like didSelectRow in ios.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your viewController

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{    
    NSInteger selectedRow = [self.tableView selectedRow];
    NSLog(@"Selected Row : %ld",(long)selectedRow);
    NSTableRowView *myRowView = [self.tableView rowViewAtRow:selectedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
}
```